# Data type compatibility with NEON intrinsics

Tags: gcc, arm, neon, intrinsics

I am working on ARM optimizations using the NEON intrinsics, from C++ code. I understand and master most of the typing issues, but I am stuck on this one:

The instruction `vzip_u8` returns a `uint8x8x2_t` value (in fact an array of two `uint8x8_t`). I want to assign the returned value to a plain `uint16x8_t`. I see no appropriate `vreinterpretq` intrinsic to achieve that, and simple casts are rejected.

Comment: Just discovered in a manual that uint8x8x2_t is called a "Vector array data type". But still no idea how to convert.

Comment: Can you publish a small snippet to demonstrate your question?

Answer (score 6):

Some definitions to answer clearly...

[NEON](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.devlib/index.html) has 32 registers, 64-bits wide (dual view as 16 registers, 128-bits wide).

> > The NEON unit can view the same register bank as:
> >
> > - sixteen 128-bit quadword registers, Q0-Q15
> > - thirty-two 64-bit doubleword registers, D0-D31.

`uint16x8_t` is a type which requires 128-bit storage thus it needs to be in an `quadword` register.

ARM NEON Intrinsics has a definition called `vector array data type` in [ARM® C Language Extensions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053a/IHI0053A_acle.pdf):

> > ... for use in load and store operations, in 
> >     table-lookup operations, and **as the result type of operations that return a pair of vectors.**

[vzip](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHCACAB.html) instruction

> > ... interleaves the elements of two vectors.
> >
> > vzip Dd, Dm

and has an [intrinsic](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) like

```
uint8x8x2_t vzip_u8 (uint8x8_t, uint8x8_t)
```

from these we can conclude that uint8x8x2_t is actually a list of two random numbered doubleword registers, because vzip instructions doesn't have any requirement on order of input registers.

Now the answer is...

`uint8x8x2_t` can contain non-consecutive two dualword registers while `uint16x8_t` is a data structure consisting of two consecutive dualword registers which first one has an even index (D0-D31 -> Q0-Q15).

Because of this you can't cast `vector array data type` with two double word registers to a quadword register... easily.

Compiler may be smart enough to assist you, or you can just force conversion however I would check the resulting assembly for correctness as well as performance.

Comment: Things are clearer now, thanks. uint8x8x2_t must be a "pseudo-type", as it describes possibly non-contiguous data. But my initial question remains: "you can just force conversion". How ???

Comment: But as i said, compiler can fix that for you. Problem is performance might suffer. You should check the binary.

Comment: My problem was I couldn't find a way to make the compiler accept a cast.

Comment: I thought you did as in your own answer.

Comment: The fact is that I don't trust this solution, which could be working "by accident". I'll have to validate it deeper...

Comment: In the guide you refer to (Section 12.2.2), int16x4x2_t is defined as struct int16x4x2_t { int16x4_t val[2]; };. When designing an alternative casting operator, is it correct to treat the 2 arrays as if they were in consecutive memory locations (since they are declared to be stored in an array of arrays)?

Comment: @Antonio Afaik this is mostly for casting registers how things layout in memory might be a completely different story. Check VLDM instruction.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208668/using-an-union-encapsulated-in-a-struct-to-bypass-conversions-for-neon-data-ty/29213705#29213705) and see if it makes any sense?

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a 128 bit vector from two 64 bit vectors using the vcombine_* intrinsics. Thus, you can achieve what you want like this.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

uint8x16_t f(uint8x8_t a, uint8x8_t b)
{
    uint8x8x2_t tmp = vzip_u8(a,b);
    uint8x16_t result;
    result = vcombine_u8(tmp.val[0], tmp.val[1]);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'll look into it (but most probably not soon, this is an sleeping project).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround: given that the `val` member of the `uint8x8x2_t` type is an array, it is therefore seen as a pointer. Casting and deferencing the pointer works ! [Whereas taking the address of the data raises an "address of temporary" warning.]

```
uint16x8_t Value= *(uint16x8_t*)vzip_u8(arg0, arg1).val;
```

It turns out that this compiles and executes as should (at least in the case I have tried). I haven't looked at the assembly code so I cannot grant it is implemented properly (I mean just keeping the value in a register instead of writing/read to/from memory.)

Comment: I am no expert, but I think that will [violate strict aliasing rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29253236/2436175). Plus the risk [mentioned by auselan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13734838/2436175) that the 2 vectors of vectors are not coupled in the same 128bit register.

Comment: From a pure declarative point of view, the two vectors in the struct must be contiguous, and this is innocuous. So we should assume that the compiler will handle the appropriate transfers between memory and registers.

Comment: You are right on this point. Yet, technically there's a strict aliasing rules violation.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same kind of problem, so I introduced [a flexible data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29213705/2436175).

I can now therefore define the following:

```
typedef NeonVectorType<uint8x16_t> uint_128bit_t; //suitable for uint8x16_t, uint8x8x2_t, uint32x4_t, etc.
typedef NeonVectorType<uint8x8_t> uint_64bit_t; //suitable for uint8x8_t, uint32x2_t, etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

Its a bug in GCC(now fixed) on 4.5 and 4.6 series.

Bugzilla link http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48252

Please take the fix from this bug and apply to gcc source and rebuild it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for contributing to this post. It does not address the current issue, which is a matter of syntactic/semantic incompatibility, and not a code generation bug in the compiler, though.